# What is the best hydrogen bond acceptor in 2-amino-N-(3-hydroxyphenyl)acetamide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen-bond

I was preparing for my first exam in organic chemistry and came across this question.

> Draw a water molecule that is hydrogen bonded to the best anticipated hydrogen bond acceptor.
>   [image: 2-amino-N-(3-hydroxyphenyl)acetamide]
>   2-amino-N-(3-hydroxyphenyl)acetamide, PubChem CID: [20238693](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/20238693)

I was thinking that it would be one of the oxygens, because of its greater electronegativity compared to nitrogen. However, I'm having a little trouble distinguishing which oxygen.

I'm leaning towards the alcohol group. My reasoning is that there is less steric hindrance preventing solvation, but I am not sure.

Comment: But also, the ketone oxygen is sp2 hybridized. Would this have an effect to increase the polarity of the bond?

Comment: There is no ketone in this compound the functional group is an amide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, a nitrogen is usually a better hydrogen bond acceptor than an oxygen. There is a brief overview on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond#Bond_strength) with a couple of values and where they were derived from.

This makes sense intuitively, too. Ammonia is a stronger base than water as it is a better proton acceptor. An amine is a stronger base than an alcohol.

In your example, 2-amino-N-(3-hydroxyphenyl)acetamide, there are three functional groups (or four if you want to count the aromatic ring, too): a primary amine, a secondary amide, and a phenolic alcohol.

The phenolic alcohol is rather acidic and not such a good hydrogen bond acceptor, as some of the lone pairs are in conjugation with the aromatic ring.
The amide is also a delocalised system, which makes the nitrogen pretty unavailable for hydrogen bonding. For this functional group, if it were separate, the π-orbital would be the HOMO, and this is where the protonation/ proton-accepting will happen; due to the delocalisation this is less so the case. An amide usually is not a good hydrogen-bond acceptor.
**The amine** is primary, which means there is much space around it and it can directly interact with the solvent. This **is a good hydrogen-bond acceptor.**

Therefore neither oxygen will be the best hydrogen-bond acceptor.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I was a little confused about the relative strength of hydrogen bond acceptors/donors so that helped a lot.

Comment: As per the answer, it of course correct since this was an exercise from a book. But in real live the matter is more complex. In a polar solvent, the molecule will probably be ionized with a $\ce{-NH3^+}$ group and a $\ce{-O^-}$ group. Then the best hydrogen bonding group will be the phenoxide. Still, the ionization will not be complete, etc. It is a pity that the books for teaching new chemists do not pay any attention to the details.